# updating shopping cart quantity (partially works)

Tags: php, html, session, shopping-cart

I have a shopping cart which at the moment allows me to add products, remove products and with 1 product in the cart I can change its quantity.

However if i have 2 products in the cart and I try to change the quantity of the first item the site crashes. It doesnt reload the page with the new quantity it just times out and you can no longer click on any other links on the website.

The code to display the quantity is:

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post">
        <input name="quantity" type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" size="1" maxlength="2" />
        <input name="adjustBtn' . $pid . '" type="submit" value="Update" />
        <input name="item_to_adjust" type="hidden" value="' . $pid . '" />
</form>
```

and the code which deals with this is here:

```
if (isset($_POST['item_to_adjust']) && $_POST['item_to_adjust'] != "") {
    // execute some code
    $item_to_adjust = $_POST['item_to_adjust'];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $quantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $quantity); // filter everything but numbers
    if ($quantity >= 100) { $quantity = 99; }
    if ($quantity < 1) { $quantity = 1; }
    if ($quantity == "") { $quantity = 1; }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart"] as $each_item) { 
              $i++;
              while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                  if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $item_to_adjust) {
                      // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
                      array_splice($_SESSION["cart"], $i-1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $item_to_adjust, "quantity" => $quantity)));
                  } // close if condition
              } // close while loop
    } // close foreach loop
}
?>
```

been looking through answers on here but cant see a solution. Can anyone help me with this? I will try and provide any other information that may be needed to help.

just to clarify, the cart works perfectly until I try to change the quantity of an item that isnt the last item I added. So if I have 3 items in the cart I cant change the quantity of item 1 or 2 but I can change item 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a starting point, may I recommend making a copy of the cart array for editing, rather than editing the array which you are currently iterating - which can lead to unexpected behaviour

Comment: Could be your loop isn't terminating.  You might try adding a if ($i > 50) die("manual termination") or something like that.

Comment: @cocogorilla I added your suggestion within the if statement inside the while loop and sure enough it kills it saying "manual termination" however I still dont know how to fix this problem :/

Comment: I would also like to add that when I do carry out the "manual termination" and I revisit the shopping cart there are 51 items in there

Comment: If you do not modify $i anywhere except in the foreach, then there are > 50 things in $_SESSION["cart"].  Do you expect only two items?  print_r($_SESSION["cart"]); die(); just before the foreach.  See what it is you are actually iterating.

Comment: @Pudge601 Thankyou the creation of a copy of the SESSION fixed that for me. I would feel a little cheeky answering this question myself so If you put that into an answer I will accept that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a copy of the cart array for editing.

Editing the array which is currently being iterated can cause unexpected behaviour.